# BeforeRightClick: Select full range when clicking random cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do I treat a range as one selection when BeforeRightClick. Now I have to click every single cell in the corresponding me.range ,however, I would like to color e.g. the whole B11:K13 when clicking a random cell in that range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B11:K13;B26:K39;B42:K45")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L8:L44")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use commas instead of semi-colons when building a range: `Me.Range("B11:K13,B26:K39,B42:K45"))` - It worked when I changed those.

Comment: Hi again @braX thanks a lot!